# Blanchard and Quah output gap

Tags: time-series, macroeconomics

In the paper of Blanchard and Quah (1989), they estimate the impact of demand shock on **delta(real GDP)**. And from that they could estimate the impact of demand shock on **real GDP** (which is output gap). But they didn't show clearly how they move from delta(realGDP) to real GDP.

Can you help me with this question? Many thanks!

Comment: For a given $x_t$, if you know $\Delta x_{t+1}$ you easily get $x_{t+1}$ as $x_{t+1}=x_t+\Delta x_{t+1}$. Does that help? In Blanchard and Quah terms, they are modelling $\Delta x_{t+1}$ and move from that to $x_{t+1}$, is that right?

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you! and so sorry for not clarifying better here. Actually they move from estimating impact of demand shock on deltaGDP to estimating impact of demand shock on GDP.

Comment: so I wonder if those two estimations are the same (so that they didn't show details in their paper)? or something else quite easy but I still couldn't get...?

Comment: That requires us to actually read the paper, doesn't it?

Comment: no, i think the paper was already from 1989 and people now have standadized the BQ method to estimate output gap so it is widely used now... i think there are some clear steps in this method... but to read the paper would take time ...

Comment: Maybe try Economics Stack Exchange instead?

Answer (score 0):

Blanchard and Quah use a structural VAR to estimate the impact of a demand shock on delta(realGDP). Using the estimate of the simultaneity matrix (that results A-B identification) you can transform the residuals of the VAR into supply and demanda shocks.

If you are using eviews, it is very easy to estimate and generate de Impulse response functions. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: thanks a lot Gustavo! Actually im using R. I already generated the IRF, but still on the way to get the output gap.

Comment: just a short question. Now that from VAR model I have got the transformed matrix of residuals and also the transformed matrix of Phi. Restriction already applied. What shoud i do next to get output gap? i guess this is the last step... Thanks in advance!

Comment: This part is very tricky. With the residuals and the matrix associated with the shocks you can generate the structural shocks.

the output gap is the acumlated impact of the demand shock on gdp growth, which you can generate using the impulse response function values.

Is there a way to send private messeges on stack exchenage? Send me your email and I can send you a excel worksheet that calculates this. It is easier to understand how its done.

Comment: Honestly i don't know how i can chat privately here. But my usual email is sarahkiss98@gmail.com. Hope you don't mind. Thanks a million times!